# Set test execution options programmatically or in settings file for a Jasmine unit test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm writing unit tests for JavaScript with Jasmine at the moment. After starting the test runner, you have the option to change the execution options by clicking the "options" button.

[image]

After changing this, the changed values are passed by GET method to the file having an URL like this:

```
test-runner.html?random=false&failFast=true&throwFailures=true
```

Does someone have an idea how I can set this values programmatically or in a settings file that they are already set like this when I open the file by just opening test-runner.html without passing values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [Env](https://jasmine.github.io/api/2.6/Env.html) object which can be accessed by calling `jasmine.getEnv();`. With this object, you can set the options in the `test-runner.html` like below.

```
<script>
  var env = jasmine.getEnv();
  env.randomizeTests(false);
  env.stopOnSpecFailure(true);
  env.throwOnExpectationFailure(true);
</script>
```

However, this does not allow you to change the options manually in the browser anymore.